# Looping through array, what is better, faster, etc?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, search, coding-style

I want to implement a Hash or PHP-like Array. What is better, option a) or option b) to find a element by its key?

(All variables are set and initialized and so on!)

a)

```
for( i = 0; i < ary->element_cnt && found == NULL; i++ ) {
    current_element = &(ary->elements[i]);
    if( 0 == memcmp(current_element->key, search_key, keysize) ) {
        found = current_element;
    }
}
```

b)

```
for( i = 0, current_element = &(ary->elements[i]) ; 
        i < ary->element_cnt &&  
        0 != memcmp(current_element->key, searchkey, keysize); 
        i++, current_element = &(ary->elements[i]) );
/*found = current_element;*/
```

Is the first one better because it is much more readable/maintainable? Will the second one be faster?

Is it "bad style" to do everything in one big loop?

I know, there are much better search algos out there, but that's not my problem here!

Comment: Will the second one _really_ be faster? Check the generated code and do some profiling first before you sacrifice readability for some perceived optimization.

Comment: Edited question. I don't know! My wording was not as good as it should have been.

Comment: It's mainly a matter of taste. In terms of performance, most of the time will be spent in entering/exiting `memcmp`, so if this accounts for a significant percent of overall time, I would try to do that differently. I often do `for (i = n; --i>=0;) if (test(i)) break;` so `i` is the found element, unless it's negative.

Comment: first is way better because it is easier to read

Comment: Being a picky embedded sort of chap, one thing that's faster is:
i = ary->element_cnt;
while(i--)
...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All matters of style are of course highly subjective. This is the type of thing that is sometimes "regulated" by local code style guides.

Personally I think the call to `memcmp()` is a bit too "heavy", I would write it as:

```
for( i = 0; i < ary->element_cnt; ++i ) {
    current_element = &ary->elements[i];
    if( memcmp(current_element->key, search_key, keysize) == 0 )
        break;
}
```

This cuts out the `found` check in the loop header, since that is effectively checking the same thing twice which I dislike.

If I *really* wanted to use `found`, I would write it as:

```
for( i = 0; i < ary->element_cnt && !found; ++i ) {
    current_element = &ary->elements[i];
    found = memcmp(current_element->key, search_key, keysize) == 0;
}
```

This removes the pointless `if` and just assigns the Boolean directly which I think is nice.

Answer (score 5):

Both of these are O(N) algorithms - they both simply loop over an array and call `memcmp` for each element - so they should perform similarly.  Subjectively, I think the first one is better because it is easier to read.

However, the best way to implement lookup by key is not with a linear search like this, but with a specialized data structure like a hash table or balanced binary tree.  Scripting languages like PHP generally use hash tables to implement lookup like this.

Comment: I don't like the reasoning of "two O(N) algorithms perform about the same". using "similar" or even better "asymptotically similar" would be better IMHO

Comment: It depends on the level of argumentation. From the algorithm and technical point of view, Charles is absolutely right. They don't even perform asymptotically similar.